# Give an example when $\|x\|_{\infty} = \|x\|_{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, vectors, normed-spaces

I am having trouble giving an example when the equality $\|x\|_{\infty} = \|x\|_{2}$ is achieved using vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I know the definitions of both norms, but I don't know how to formally write an example with general vectors to show when there is equality...

What I've tried:

For $\|x\|_{\infty} = \|x\|_{2}$, let $x = (x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})$ and let $x_{max}$ be the maximum element in $x$. Then:

$\|x\|_{\infty} = \|x\|_{2}$

$\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\max}|x_{i}|=\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{2} \right )^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$x_{max} = (|x_{1}|^{2}+|x_{2}|^{2}+\cdots +|x_{n}|^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Therefore, $x$ must be the vectors $x = (x_{max},0,...,0), (0,x_{max},...,0), ..., $ or $ (0,0,...,x_{max})$, since $\sqrt{x_{max}^{2}}=x_{max}$.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your reasoning here.

Comment: Define $x_{\max} = \max \{|x_1|,|x_2|,\cdots,|x_n|\}$ instead of the maximum element in $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: $(-x_\text{max},0,0,\ldots,0)$ would do as well. Think about the $2$-norm vs the $\infty$-norm as a ($n$-dimensional) sphere inscribed in a ($n$-dimensional) cube. It touches the cube in exactly $2^n$ points.

Comment: In fact, $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ is an example. (The question was "Give an example," right? So just one single  vector that meets the criterion should be enough. You seem to be trying to find every possible vector tere could be, which is far more than _an_ example.)

Comment: Thank you everyone! To David K, the professor specifically asked to use general vectors when giving an example, unfortunately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an explicit example, just let $c\in \mathbb{R}$, and define $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ as $x=(c,0,...0)$ and certainly $\|x\|_\infty=\|x\|_2$.

You can also see this from a geometric perspective. Consider the unit balls under the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ norms. The only vectors where the norms coincide are where the unit balls intersect.

Note in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have exactly four points of intersection: at $(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)$. Of course, you can scale the balls so they are no longer unit balls but have radius $r$ and the points of intersection would scale to $(r,0), (-r,0), (0,r), (0,-r)$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $2^n$ intersection points. The *only* vectors where the norm equality $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}=\|\cdot\|_{2}$ holds are where the balls intersect.

Comment: That's very interesting of you to say! I never thought about looking at it geometrically. Thank you ~